# Problem compiling C progtam from command line gcc with math.h

Tags: c, command-line, terminal, math.h

I am new to the command line and I am trying to run a C program containing the function `log10`.

If I give

```
gcc -o -lm randomVamp random\ vampire.c
```

I get the error

```
gcc: error: randomVamp: No such file or directory
```

but *randomVamp* is the name I wanted to give to the executable, of course it doesn't exist yet.

If I prompt just

```
gcc -o -lm random\ vampire.c
```

then I get the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbWivPU.o: in function `main':
random vampire.c:(.text+0x312): undefined reference to `log10'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

I don't know if it's relevant, but the program also includes `stdlib.h` and `time.h` should I use some flag or link them in some way?

Comment: If you want to give a name to output file, it should follow the `-o` switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-o` means that the **next** argument is the output file name. Replace `-o -lm randomVamp` with something like `-o randomVamp -lm`.

Also, note that `-l...` have no effect if specified before the `.c`/`.cpp`/`.o`/... files. So, the command could look like this:

```
gcc -o randomVamp random\ vampire.c -lm
```